# Android switch view track size

Tags: android, view, uiswitch

Current state:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/priRl.jpg)

Need:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLjwl.jpg)

track changes size depending on the size of thumb

Doesn't work

```
android:switchMinWidth="52dp"
```

My xml code:
activity_main.xml

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchViewOn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Switch On"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/switch_track"
    tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchViewOff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch Off"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/switch_track"
    tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" />
```

switch_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="32dp" />
            <size android:width="32dp" android:height="32dp" />
            <stroke android:width="8dp" android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

switch_track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#FF7733" />
            <corners android:radius="32dp" />
            <size android:width="52dp" android:height="32dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#D5D5D6" />
            <corners android:radius="32dp" />
            <size android:width="52dp" android:height="32dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Did it work? Can you show by writing the code here please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried changing Switch to
"androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat"
because the thumb is not letting the width
change also your android:switchMinWidth="52dp" did not work. The
output reached is not similar but to some extent it is nearly
working.
Also since using androidx so had to change these as well -
`app:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb" app:track="@drawable/switch_track"`

Output:[image: Zpb81.png]

activity_mail.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switchViewOn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="380dp"
    android:text="@string/switch_on"
    app:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
    app:track="@drawable/switch_track"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switchViewOff"
    tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" />

 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat

 android:id="@+id/switchViewOff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
    android:text="@string/switch_off"
    app:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
    app:track="@drawable/switch_track"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/switchViewOn"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/switchViewOn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```